# QT Quick Compat release build not running

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

At the moment I try to build a simple qt Quick-project for different platforms as release build.  Unfortunately, after I build it for Windows and added all necessary dependencies (via windeploy and manually) nothing happens after I clicked on the executable, not even when I execute it in the console. What could be the reason for that and how could I fix it?

While trying to fix my issue myself I tried to build a tutorial QT Widget Application from QT Creator which ran with the same compiler kit flawlessly. After that I tried to build a QT-Quick tutorial project also with the same kit (qmlcharts) and in contrast to my own project at least a tiny but empty window pops up.(usually there should be charts in it, see Image 1).

[image: empty tiny window]
Image1

Be aware that for any case I explained here the build and run button in debug-mode opened the application correct and displayed everything the right way. Only the execution of the release build makes problems. I append a screenshot of my current Compiler and Debugger QT Kit,. Maybe this helps.

[image]
Image2

[image]
Image3

[image]
Image4

Answer (score 0):

OK, i fixed it. The problem was, that when i executed windeployqt for dependency-management I didn´t give the qml directory as an parameter. If you want to use windeploy with qml, you have to add this parameter. Unfortunately in no tutorial i saw this was mentioned! The official command in that case is: `./windeployqt --qmldir "your qml folder within your qt-installation folder" "the folder path to your release executable"`